# Optimize if else statement becauase of null checks, using lambda?

Tags: java

I have the following example, which feels not well readable.
There are lots of checks I have to do because getStudents() could be null and getTests() could be also null. I have to do isStudentsAvailable() and then isTestAvailable().

How could I transfer this example to a lambda expression, which does not need those checks?
Would be happy about some hints. Thanks

```
      if(school.isStudentsAvailable()){
        sendMailtoStudents(school.getStudents());
        
        if(school.getStudents().isTestAvailable()) {
        printTests(school.getStudents().getTests());
         }
      }
```

Comment: "could be null", you mean they can return null? One thing not related to lambda is to let methods like getStudents() return an empty collection instead of null, that would remove some checks and depending on how sendMailtoStudents & printTests works you might not need to change them at all

Comment: Using if statements this way is completely fine. Don't try to fix what's not broken.

Answer (score 4):

> There are lots of checks I have to do because getStudents() could be null and getTests() could be also null

Ah, you have a code smell.

There are many ways to deal with the concept of NUI (Not initialized, Unknown, Irrelevant). `null` is one way, wrapper types like Optional is another, annotations is a third, and sentinel values are a fourth.

But it sounds like this isn't a case of NUI! It sounds like `getStudents()` is returning null as a way to convey: There are zero students.

In other words, that it is conveying Empty, and not NUI.

It is **wrong** to represent empty with null, because unlike NUI, empty has semantic meaning that fits within the contract of your type. `school.getStudents` returns a list (or set or collection or map or array - some type representing a collection), and all of these types are capable of representing an empty type just fine.

In other words, the fix is to go to the code of the `getStudents` method and replace `return null;` with `return List.of();`.

Then your calling code is much simpler. Instead of:

```
List<Student> students = getStudents();
if (students != null) {
    for (Student student : students) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

it simplifies to:

```
for (Student student : getStudents()) {
    // code here
}
```

which eyeballs will immediately like, no doubt. It's much easier to read.

But, let's say you can't change getStudents because it is provided.

Then you do what you should always do when faced with APIs so badly designed they are borderline broken: Write a wrapper:

```
public static List<Student> fixedGetStudents(School school) {
    List<Student> students = school.getStudents();
    return students == null ? List.of() : students;
}
```

and call that. Trying to 'fix it' every time you use it means you're writing code to address the potential nullity *every time* you want to use getStudents, and this is a style error, in that it violates DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself).